# Should a view use dispatch or fire events?

Tags: sencha-touch

What is the best way for a view to communicate with its controller? Most examples use `Ext.dispatch`, but this seems wrong to me for a few reasons:

1. It couples the view to the controller, making the view hard to reuse. If the view is nested inside another view, it may no longer be desirable - or even correct - to call the same controller/action.
2. Having the view dictate to the controller which action to take inverts the hierarchy. Commands should go down, events should go up.

So, should views always fire events, and never call specific controllers? This way the parent view (if any) or the instantiating controller can decide how to respond. In this case a containing view should bubble up child events it doesn't handle, so they can be handled higher up in the hierarchy.

OR

Should views *prefer* to fire events over invoking specific controller actions, but not go to extremes? I emphasize prefer, because I can think of cases when a view should always trigger the same action, e.g. a Logout button. This seems like a slippery slope... how do you know for sure that you will never need to override that button's action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always let my views fire events.  As you outlined, there are cases where dispatch works fine and you don't have to worry about much... but why bother?  I like the consistency of always letting the view fire events.

Comment: So, where do you handle the events - inside parent views, or only at the controller level?

Comment: Always at the controller level.

Comment: OK, that sounds reasonable. But if the controller creates a view with  several nested views, it can quickly become inundated with dozens of events that don't have any obvious relation to that view. If views don't have the ability to handle and "swallow" child events locally, then how do you handle the escalating complexity? Shouldn't each view be associated with its own controller? This decoupling principle gets tricky rather quickly. :)

Comment: I don't think each view has to have its own controller but that is generally how I do it.  Also, check out this recent post which discusses controller inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628306/how-to-perform-controller-inheritance-in-extjs-4