# ExtJs4 How to Add default event to GridPanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I wanna all gridpanel have selectionchange event;

Because I have some Grid in one Page,I need get currentGrid to do something;

such as :

var activeGrid

```
selectionchange:function(){
activeGrid = this;
}
```

then i can get currentGrid. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.override('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  initComponent: function(config) {
    this.callOverridden(arguments);

    this.on({
      selectionchange: this.mySelectionFunction,
      scope: this
    });
  },
  mySelectionFunction: function() {
    // Do your stuff here
  }
});
```

Do you need some explanations on this?

Comment: Wow... that would change how selectionchange even works in ALL grid panels in your app. I don't think it was desired by OP.

Comment: @sha "I wanna all gridpanel have selectionchange event;". I think that by "all" he meant all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [How to Perform Controller Inheritance in ExtJS 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628306/how-to-perform-controller-inheritance-in-extjs-4/9628534#9628534)

I posted some examples on how to create base functionality in view/controllers. I think you will find what you're looking for.