# Extjs 4, Event handling, scope, custom components

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have following problem. I have grid with `tbar`. Inside `tbar` I have number of `Ext.form.field.Trigger`.

When the user click on trigger button I want to filter the store using function that is provided with `grid`. I want to define functionality of `triggerclick` inside defined `class`, so I can reuse this component with different `grid`.

So, in short I want to find the panel where clicked component is placed and call panel function, or pass reference of panel to `triggerclick`, or fire an event with some parameter that will calculated based on where the button was clicked, or maybe there is a better method to accomplish this.

> The code (FilterField -> extension of trigger):

```
Ext.define('GSIP.core.components.FilterField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger',
    alias: 'widget.filterfield',
    initComponent: function() {

        this.addEvents('filterclick');
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    onTriggerClick: function(e, t) {

        //Ext.getCmp('gsip_plan_list').filterList(); - working but dont want this

        //this.fireEvent('filterclick'); - controller cant see it,

        //this.filterList; - is it possible to pass scope to panel or reference to panel

        //e.getSomething() - is it possible to get panel via EventObject? smth like e.getEl().up(panel)


    }
});
```

---

> code of panel:

```
Ext.define('GSIP.view.plans.PlanReqList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.gsip_devplan_list',
    id: 'gsip_plan_list',
    title: i18n.getMsg('gsip.view.PlanReqList.title'),
    layout: 'fit',
    initComponent: function() {

        this.store = 'DevPlan';

        this.tbar = [{
            xtype: 'filterfield',
            id: 'filter_login',
            triggerCls: 'icon-user',
            //scope:this - how to pass scope to panel without defining onTriggerClick here
            //          onTriggerClick: function() { 
            //              this.fireEvent('filterclick'); //working event is fired but controller cant see it
            //              this.filterList; //this is working but i dont want to put this code in every filterfield
            //          },
            //          listeners : {
            //              filterclick: function(btn, e, eOpts) { //this is working

            //              }
            //            },
        }];

        this.columns = [{
            id: 'id',
            header: "Id",
            dataIndex: "id",
            width: 50,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true
        }, {
            header: "Name",
            dataIndex: "name",
            width: 150,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true
        }, {
            header: "Author",
            dataIndex: "author",
            sortable: true,
            renderer: this.renderLogin,
            filterable: true
        }];

        this.callParent(arguments);


    },
    filterList: function() {
        this.store.clearFilter();

        this.store.filter({
            property: 'id',
            value: this.down("#filter_id").getValue()
        }, {
            property: 'name',
            value: this.down("#filter_name").getValue()
        });
    },
    renderLogin: function(value, metadata, record) {
        return value.login;
    }
});
```

---

> part of code of Controller:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'attachments': {
            filesaved: this.scanSaved,
        }
    }, {
        'scan': {
            filesaved: this.attachmentSaved
        }
    }, {
        '#filter_login': {
            filterclick: this.filterStore //this is not listened 
        }
    });
},
filterStore: function() {
    console.log('filtering store');

    this.getPlanListInstance().filter();
},
```

Comment: Not really sure what's not working in your question. You posted a lot of code, but didn't tell us where exactly the problem is. But your task seems very familiar to what I've been doing in my project. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628306/how-to-perform-controller-inheritance-in-extjs-4/9628534#9628534 for some explanation on how to re-use components and controllers.

Comment: I have panel with filterfield. This panel also have function filterList. How to easily call filterList from filterfield. Filterfield is extension of Trigger so the call should be from onTriggerClick (and i want to put the call inside class definition - first code sample)

Comment: Well.. you can do up('panel') to get reference to the panel your component in and call method from there. But I would not recommend that. Instead I would either subscribe to filterfield events in panel class or generate event and subscribed to it in controller.

Comment: how to do up('panel') - the onTriggerClick receives EventObject and target. How to get component from them? so i can call up function. I will try other ways you described

Comment: i need some hint how to subscribe to component events in other component without using controller

Comment: But I thought you did in your code already? You already had event 'filterclick' fired by trigger field, and handler for this event defined in the panel view, no?

Comment: Should it really work this way? If i declare a listener in panel, and fire event in some other component - panel will not be notified, am i right ? It works in controllers because controllers got selectors for matching exact type of component. Here is something that i need but requires to create an observable object: http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=simplebus

Comment: Ideally you want to use controllers and whole MVC architecture.

Comment: Yes, but it is not working. Controller does not see filterclick event. Does controller listen to custom objects or only views ?

Comment: Controller can listen to anything. Just need to specify exactly what to. But I would fire events on the panel level - add this into your trigger handler: `this.up('panel').fireEvent('triggerclicked');`

Comment: `this.up('panel').fireEvent('triggerclicked');` this way component is not reusable the way i want, i have to provide different function for each panel (to get specific store and filter it). But you pointed me to solution, i am like 90% sure i tried this before but now it is working `this.up('panel').filterList()`. This way if i put method filterList in parent panel it will be working. Thanks

Comment: I will post that comment as answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller can listen to anything. Just need to specify exactly what to. But I would fire events on the panel level - add this into your trigger handler:

```
this.up('panel').fireEvent('triggerclicked');
```